# How to format multi value field as a grid?

Tags: 7, entities

I created content type "photo gallery" that have multi-value field of images - for user convenience. I would like to create a view, that would show all that kind of galleries with their titles on one page, formatted as grid. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a *similar type* of requirement to display in a **grid/table layout** multiple *"Related"* nodes rendered with a particular *view mode (added with Display Suite)*, referenced through an Entity Reference field.
We came up with the following module: [Grid Field Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/grid_field_formatter), which is now available with a stable release.

If you look at the [screenshots on the project page](http://drupal.org/files/project-images/20130224GFF_front-end-result-v2.jpg) or the description in the content you should be able to find that it would seem to correspond to the initial requirements you described.

Feel free to let us know if I missed something, this doesn't work, or if you would have any more questions, comments or issues related with this requirement or module, I would be glad to provide more information or explain in more details.

Any more feedback, reporting, testing, comments or questions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!